# Qual a diferença entre passar nil no synchronize/queue de um Task/Thread?

Tags: delphi, thread, task

Na maioria dos exemplos que encontrei a estrutura de uma Task básica é:

```
procedure
var
  FTask : ITask;
begin
  FTask := TTask.Run(
  procedure
  begin
    //código a ser executado dentro da Task;
    TThread.synchronize(TThread.CurrentThread,
    procedure
    begin
      //Código que executa dentro da Thread principal;
    end);
  end;
  );
end;
```

Onde `TThread.CurrentThread` indica qual em qual Thread o código vai executar, mas já vi também exemplos de código em que no lugar de `TThread.CurrentThread` é passado `nil`, qual a diferença? Como funciona? O SO vai decidir por conta própria qual Thread vai executar o código?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isso não é onde o codigo vai ser executado, mas sim com que thread vai ele sincronizar. No caso de passar nil vai ser com a Main Thread (só há uma) a TThread.CurrentThread representa a thread atual, qualquer que seja

Comment: Entendi, Muito obrigado.